# jess How can i fix this error?

Tags: jess

Jess reported an error in routine call

```
 while executing (call ?fopc charAt ?index)
 while executing (bind ?c (call ?fopc charAt ?index))

 Message: Called method threw an exception.
```

The program is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the Java method charAt there can be two reasons for an exception.

1. `?fopc` isn't bound to an object java.lang.String (or one of the other classes where `charAt` is defined).
2. The third argument `?index` is not less that the string's length or negative.

Provide a full Jess example - no links, please - to reproduce the error.